# difficulty with deep breathing, should I persevere?

Tags: running, breathing

I'm currently training fitness generally and a big part of that for me is running, I noticed that the hardest part was breathing fast enough and at some point I'd usually lose a breathing rhythm and sputter. after looking at breathing techniques from multiple sources I found out that I am a 'chest-breather' and would be better served breathing from my stomach. However, I have found that no matter how long I concentrate on developing my 'stomach-breathing' as soon as I stop being conscious of my breathing I revert to the chest, and especially if I am running, I can't get enough oxygen with the more diaphragmatic approach. I also find it difficult to breath with my stomach when full and i was asking for any advice on how to change my breathing habits.

Comment: Do you enjoy running? If so, stop focusing on breathing and just keep running. You'll develop your own rhythm after a while.

Comment: If you're running so hard that you can't keep up breathing, you need to slow down. At a moderate pace, you should be able to hold a conversation while running.

Comment: "...also find it difficult to breath with my stomach when full...". You should not be running after eating either.